# The geometric representation $D_3$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Can anyone help me to understand why $V$ is irreducible?

Its an example, where we let $V$ be the representation of $D_3$ (the geometric representation of $D_3$). We will show that $V$ is irreducible.

Since $\operatorname{dim}(V)=2$ we need to show that $V$ has no subrepresentations $W$ with $\dim(W)=1$. So we let $W$ be a subspace with $\dim(W)=1$ and proceed to show that there is some $g \in D_3$ and some $w \in W$ such that $gw \notin W$.

I understand all above and don't understand the rest:

But since $\dim(W)=1$, if $gw \in W$ then $gw= \lambda w$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, so the claim is that no vector is simultaneously an eigenvector for all the matrices the representation $G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is given by (there are six matrices, $e,r,s,r^2,sr,sr^2$).

Clearly the eigenvectors of the matrix  corresponding to $s$ are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ (up to a choice of scalar multiple for each). Buth neither of these will also be an eigenvector for the matrix corresponding to $r$. This shows that $V$ is irreducible.

$$s \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad  
r \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Where does the $\lambda$ come from?  what does "no vector is simultaneously an eigenvector for all the martrices ..." mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to show is that there is no one-dimensional linear subspace of $V$ that is closed under the action of $D_3$. Since $D_3$ is generated by $r$ and $s$, this is equivalent to showing that there is no simultaneous eigenvector in $V$ for the action of $r$ and $s$. For if $0 \neq v \in V$ is such an eigenvector, with eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$ for $r,s$ respectively. Then $W := \mathbb{F} \cdot v$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $V$, and $r^a s^b \cdot v = \lambda^a \mu^b v$ so that $W$ is closed under the action of $D_3$, whilst conversely if $W$ is any one-dimensional subspace of $V$ closed under the action of $V$ then any non-zero $v \in W$ is a simultaneous eigenvector for the action of $r$ and $s$.

So now it is easy to see that the eigenvectors of $s$ are $e_1$ and $e_2$ with eigenvalues $1,-1$ respectively. But neither $e_1$ or $e_2$ are an eigenvector for $r$, and so we're done.

Comment: Thank you :) But how do we know that "if 0≠∈ is such an eigenvector, with eigenvalues , for , respectively. Then :=⋅ is a one-dimensional subspace of "?

Comment: Check what it means to be a one-dimensional subspace of $V$: Firstly, it is certainly a subspace because given any $\alpha,\beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{F}$ then $(\alpha v) + \gamma(\beta v) = (\alpha + \gamma \beta v) \in \mathbb{F} \cdot v$, and so $\mathbb{F} \cdot v$ is closed under linear combinations and $0 \in \mathbb{F} \cdot v$ clearly. Then $\mathbb{F} \cdot v$ is spanned by the single non-zero element $v$ and so $\{ v \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F} \cdot v$ (a singleton set containing a non-zero element is lin indep) and so $\mathbb{F} \cdot v$ is one-dimensional.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought about it but then for some reason I couldn't accomplish it as an answer for my question. Is there a definition for simultaneous eigenvector?

Comment: If $V$ is a $\mathbb{F}$-vector space. Let $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{F}}(V)$ denote the ring of $\mathbb{F}$-linear endomorphisms of $V$. Then if $S$ is any non-empty subset of $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{F}}(V)$, then we say that $v \in V$ is a simultaneous eigenvector for $S$ if $v \neq 0$ and for all $s \in S$ there exists some $\lambda_s \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $ s(v) = \lambda_s v$. That is, $v$ is an eigenvector for every $s \in S$ (i.e simultaneously).